# Attempt to invoke virtual method boolean in react-native app

Tags: react-native

Attempt to invoke virtual method boolean com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.ReaLayoutAnimator.isLayoutAnimationEnabled() ona null object reference ..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use this versions
"react-native-reanimated": "1.13.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "1.7.0",